# how to add new key and value to multidimensional in PHP without using the loops....?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mongodb

```
Array ( [0] => Array (
            [date] => 01-06-2018 
            [nav] => 30.65100 ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [date] => 31-05-2018 
            [nav] => 30.84900 ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [date] => 30-05-2018 
            [nav] => 30.73200 ) 
        [3] => Array ( 
            [date] => 29-05-2018 
            [nav] => 30.81500 )
```

The above code is the Multi-array, we have added a common id like id_code = 0089 to every array in it without using any loops in PHP. Can anyone helps me and it is possible or not .....?

Comment: It's very clear, it's not possible without a loop.

Comment: Thank you dude(Kris roofe).for your help.

Comment: yet another givve me teh codez question with the "no loop" flavor, fyi there's always a loop in there internally. what is wrong with using a `foreach` anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean not manually loop through the array then yes, it is possible using [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
$array = [
0 => [
    "date" => "01-06-2018", 
    "nav" => "30.65100"], 
1 => [ 
    "date" => "01-06-2018", 
    "nav" => "30.65100"], 
2 => [ 
    "date" => "01-06-2018", 
    "nav" => "30.65100"], 
3 => [ 
    "date" =>"01-06-2018", 
    "nav" => "30.65100"]
    ];

array_walk($array, function(&$item1) {
    $item1['id_code'] = "0089";
});

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 01-06-2018
            [nav] => 30.65100
            [id_code] => 0089
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 01-06-2018
            [nav] => 30.65100
            [id_code] => 0089
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 01-06-2018
            [nav] => 30.65100
            [id_code] => 0089
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 01-06-2018
            [nav] => 30.65100
            [id_code] => 0089
        )

)
```

Demo https://3v4l.org/lCGIO

Comment: I had assumed IDs will be different since all other values are different...

Comment: @user3153340: updated, the date and number in my array in my code aren't quoted so it interpreted as numbers, then PHP performs rounding and calculating. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

An effective solution will be to use array_map function as:

```
$keyValue = 'some value';

$data = array_map(function($d) use ($keyValue){
    return $d + ['keyName' => $keyValue];
}, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the closer you can get, but it is probably not your expected result. The exact result you need cannot be done without using a loop as far as I know.

```
$t = array( 0 => array( 'date' => '01-06-2018', 'nav' => '30.65100' ), 1 => array( 'date' => '31-05-2018', 'nav' => '30.84900' ), 2 => array( 'date' => '30-05-2018', 'nav' => '30.73200' ), 3 => array( 'date' => '29-05-2018', 'nav' => '30.81500' ));
$tt = array( 0 => array( 'id' => '648'), 1 => array( 'id' => '332'), 2 => array( 'id' => '889'), 3 => array( 'id' => '285') );
$final = array_map(null, $t, $tt);
print_r($final);
```

The output will look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 01-06-2018
                    [nav] => 30.65100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 648
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 31-05-2018
                    [nav] => 30.84900
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 332
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 30-05-2018
                    [nav] => 30.73200
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 889
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 29-05-2018
                    [nav] => 30.81500
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 285
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, dude but i need to add a value to same key